# Overriding dependencies version in maven plugin

Tags: maven, dependencies, pom.xml, parent-pom

My project's pom contains:

```
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.tomcat.maven/tomcat7-maven-plugin -->
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
        <artifactId>tomcat7-maven-plugin</artifactId> 
        <version>2.2</version>
    </plugin>
```

I use this Maven plugin ([tomcat7-maven-plugin](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.tomcat.maven/tomcat7-maven-plugin)) to test my war file by running:

```
mvn tomcat7:run
```

The plugin itself is a [module](https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/tomcat/maven/tomcat7-maven-plugin/2.2/tomcat7-maven-plugin-2.2.pom) of a multi-module project [tomcat-maven-plugin](https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/tomcat/maven/tomcat-maven-plugin/2.2/tomcat-maven-plugin-2.2.pom).

Partial content of tomcat-maven-plugin-2.2.pom (parent/reactor):

```
<groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
<artifactId>tomcat-maven-plugin</artifactId>
<packaging>pom</packaging>
<name>Apache Tomcat Maven Plugin</name>
<version>2.2</version>
<properties>
    <tomcat7Version>7.0.47</tomcat7Version>
</properties>
```

Partial content of tomcat7-maven-plugin-2.2.pom (module):

```
<parent>
    <artifactId>tomcat-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
    <version>2.2</version>
</parent>
<artifactId>tomcat7-maven-plugin</artifactId>
<packaging>maven-plugin</packaging>
<name>Apache Tomcat Maven Plugin :: Tomcat 7.x</name>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
        <artifactId>tomcat-embed-core</artifactId>
        <version>${tomcat7Version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
        <artifactId>tomcat-util</artifactId>
        <version>${tomcat7Version}</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

As you can see from these poms, tomcat7-maven-plugin module contains lots of tomcat dependencies. The version for these dependencies is managed centrally from parent's property **tomcat7Version**.

In the example above the version of tomcat-embed-core and tomcat-util dependencies is 7.0.47, as defined in parent's pom.

I am looking for a way to override the **tomcat7Version** property.
I can definitely override all the tomcat dependencies in my projects's pom, like this:

```
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.tomcat.maven/tomcat7-maven-plugin -->
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
        <artifactId>tomcat7-maven-plugin</artifactId> 
        <version>2.2</version>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
                <artifactId>tomcat-embed-core</artifactId>
                <version>7.0.109</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
                <artifactId>tomcat-util</artifactId>
                <version>7.0.109</version>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </plugin>
```

But it is not an elegant way to resolve the need. There are currently 18 dependencies, and in general there can be any number of them. So overriding a version of each dependency can be messy.

Is it possible to override the *tomcat7Version* property from within the **project's pom**?
The general idea is to centrally override a parameter, defined in parent's pom.

Comment: Define the needed version via pluginManagement in your own project...

Comment: @khmarbaise Could you give an example?

Answer (score 0):

You can define a plugin via pluginManagement like this:

```
<build>
  <pluginManagement>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>..</groupId>
        <artifactId>..</artifactId>
        <version>..</version>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </pluginManagement>
</build>
```

Comment: With the proposed solution you can change the version of a plugin artifact. I need to change version of its dependencies.

Comment: You can also add other dependencies here.